# colorbox problem when reading image from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, colorbox

I'm developing a project using asp.net mvc. And i am saving images to database as byte array. 
Every thing works properly until when iam using colorbox.

I try to using colorbox to show set of product images. when i am click to button i am getting weird result. I am expecting image but its gathering huge amount of weird symbols like below.

<�<�="=a=�=�> >`>�>�?!?a?�?�@#@d@�@�A)AjA�A�B0BrB�B�C:C}C�DDGD�D�EEUE�E�F"FgF�F�G5G{G�HHKH�H�IIcI�I�J7J}J�KKSK�K�L*LrL�MMJM�M�N%NnN�OOIO�O�P'PqP�QQPQ�Q�R1R|R�SS_S�S�TBT�T�U(UuU�VV\V�V�WDW�W�X/X}X�YYiY�ZZVZ�Z�[E[�[�\5\�

Iam sure that works properly including colorbox. Problem occurs when colorbox tries ta get image from database. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
public FileContentResult Index(int id)
    {
        var media = _entities.Images.AsQueryable()
            .Where(e => e.Id == id)
            .Select(e => e).FirstOrDefault();
        return File(media.ImageData, media.ImageMimeType);
    }
```

this is hove i get the image.

```
http://localhost:2632/assets/index/105
```

this is the pattern of url. for getting image.

```
$("a[rel=" + "'" + 48 + "']").colorbox({ transition: "fade", title: true, current: true });
```

this is how i call color box.

```
<a style=" display:none;" rel="48" href="assets/index/107">asd</a>
```

this is the how i embed the element to page.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution available at [Problem while working with Jquery colorbox and dynamic images that reading via Aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849648/problem-while-working-with-jquery-colorbox-and-dynamic-images-that-reading-via-as)

> Use colorbox's photo property.
>   Example:
>
> $('a.example').colorbox(**{photo:true}**);
>
> The reason is that colorbox's regex to
>   auto-detect image URLs is going to
>   fail for that kind of URL (doesn't
>   contain an image-type extension).

Comment: This helped me big time. I had the same issue. This is not language-specific. When pulling images from a db or via a data uri, it will come back as the data and not render the photo unless you use this setting.

Comment: Fancybox has the same issue. use $("a[rel=photos]").fancybox({type:image});

Answer (score 0):

The weird symbols you've posted are because the bytes are being interpreted as text, and they won't all be valid/printable characters. This is not necessarily a problem.

What happens when you send a request (`http://localhost:2632/assets/index/105`)? What does the browser show?

What datatype is the field in the database? Make sure you're not using a text field, as this would certainly screw things up. It might be worthwhile copy/pasting the bytes you're saving to the database and the ones you're getting back out and checking whether they're the same. If they're not, then chances are something is wrong in the database (like the field type).

Comment: http://localhost:2632/assets/index/105 this returns image that i want to see. By the way, jquery lightbox working without any problem. but others are problem.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. If the url loads the image correctly, where are you *not* seeing the image, but expect to?

Comment: colorbox not loading the image. yes thats true its strange.