# Strange chars on ColorBox on image from Webapi

Tags: jquery, colorbox, asp.net-web-api

i'm creating a image galery with jquery colorbox plugin and for images i'm using the asp.net webapi to manipulate sizes and crops.

My problem occurs when i click on the thumbnail, and the box tha is opened does not display the image i whated but a lot of strange chars inside the box, as im loading a flat text file instead of a image.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thats the code:

```
<a class="gal_4" href="/api/CDN/GaleryImage/25" rel="image"><img src="/api/CDN/GaleryThumbnail/25" alt="" /></a>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".gal_4").colorbox({ rel: 'gal_4' });

    });
</script>
```

and for the webapi who produces the returned image:

```
HttpResponseMessage rv = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
MemoryStream oMS;

... Load image byte array on Memory stream ...

rv.Content = new ByteArrayContent(oMS.ToArray());
rv.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");

return rv;
```

when i point the src attribute of an image tag in my html it works very well, but not with colorbox, any idea?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `photo` property

`If true, this setting forces Colorbox to display a link as a photo. Use this when automatic photo detection fails (such as using a url like 'photo.php' instead of 'photo.jpg')`

Similar question: [Problem while working with Jquery colorbox and dynamic images that reading via Aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849648/problem-while-working-with-jquery-colorbox-and-dynamic-images-that-reading-via-a)